# Why is my code not working for test input? - Project Euler 549

Tags: python, debugging

This problem can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=549) and is as follows:

> The smallest number m such that 10 divides m! is m=5.
>
> The smallest number m such that 25 divides m! is m=10.
>
> Let s(n) be the smallest number m such that n divides m!.
>
> So s(10)=5 and s(25)=10.
>
> Let S(n) be ∑s(i) for 2 ≤ i ≤ n.
>
> S(100)=2012.
>
> Find S(10⁸).

Here is my code, as you can see, it is a completely brute-force solution, which seems to run in a few minutes for 10 ** 8, in addition to this, s(10) = 5 and s(25) = 10 (according to my program), as the problem says, in addition to this, I have also generated some random numbers and checked them:

```
def is_int(x): return int(x) == x

factorials = [1] 
for i in range(1, 25):
    factorials.append(factorials[-1] * i)

def s(n):
    i = 2 
    while not is_int(factorials[i] / n): i += 1
    return i

def S(x):
    S = 0 

    for n in range(2, x + 1): 
        if n % 10 ** 5 == 0: print("{0}% done!".format(n / x * 100))
        S += s(n)   

    return S
```

I have checked the precomputed factorial values, and they are correct.

The output for S(100) is 1221, when it should be 2012, here are my values
for s(n):

```
s(2) = 2
s(3) = 3
s(4) = 4
s(5) = 5
s(6) = 3
s(7) = 7
s(8) = 4
s(9) = 6
s(10) = 5
s(11) = 11
s(12) = 4
s(13) = 13
s(14) = 7
s(15) = 5
s(16) = 6
s(17) = 17
s(18) = 6
s(19) = 19
s(20) = 5
s(21) = 7
s(22) = 11
s(23) = 19
s(24) = 4
s(25) = 10
s(26) = 13
s(27) = 9
s(28) = 7
s(29) = 20
s(30) = 5
s(31) = 19
s(32) = 8
s(33) = 11
s(34) = 17
s(35) = 7
s(36) = 6
s(37) = 19
s(38) = 19
s(39) = 13
s(40) = 5
s(41) = 20
s(42) = 7
s(43) = 20
s(44) = 11
s(45) = 6
s(46) = 19
s(47) = 19
s(48) = 6
s(49) = 14
s(50) = 10
s(51) = 17
s(52) = 13
s(53) = 19
s(54) = 9
s(55) = 11
s(56) = 7
s(57) = 19
s(58) = 20
s(59) = 20
s(60) = 5
s(61) = 20
s(62) = 20
s(63) = 7
s(64) = 8
s(65) = 13
s(66) = 11
s(67) = 20
s(68) = 17
s(69) = 20
s(70) = 7
s(71) = 19
s(72) = 6
s(73) = 20
s(74) = 20
s(75) = 10
s(76) = 19
s(77) = 11
s(78) = 13
s(79) = 19
s(80) = 6
s(81) = 9
s(82) = 20
s(83) = 19
s(84) = 7
s(85) = 17
s(86) = 20
s(87) = 20
s(88) = 11
s(89) = 20
s(90) = 6
s(91) = 13
s(92) = 19
s(93) = 20
s(94) = 19
s(95) = 19
s(96) = 8
s(97) = 20
s(98) = 14
s(99) = 11
s(100) = 10
```

Please can you say why the code does not work?

Comment: python 2 or python 3? python 2 would need to cast to float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite likely this function is the source of all problems:

```
def is_int(x): 
    return int(x) == x
```

If you're trying to check whether a number is divisible by another number, this isn't the best way to do it. Especially with higher order numbers, floating point representations tend to get dicey. Just use the `%` operator, like this:

```
def s(n):
    i = 2 
    while factorials[i] % n: 
        i += 1
    return i
```

Also, if you want S(100), you'd probably want to store factorials all the way to 100! too?

```
factorials = [1] 
for i in range(1, 101): # note this
    factorials.append(factorials[-1] * i)
```

And now:

```
In[]:
S(100)

Out[]:
2012
```

Comment: When using the faulty code, s(n) would always be <= 24, for n <= 10 ** 8, so I had only calculated to 24, but now that the s(n) function actually works, I will need to calculate all the way up to 100!.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function `def is_int(x): return int(x) == x` is running into problems with the limited precision of a float.

```
for i in range(1,100):
    fraction = 10**i/(10**i-1)
    if fraction == int(fraction):
        print(i)
        break
```

returns `16`.

Your calculation would be safe if instead of checking for equality between the float value and integer

```
while not is_int(factorials[i] / n): 
    i += 1
```

you checked if the modulo is 0, thus `factorials[i]` can be divided by `n`:

```
while not (factorials[i] % n == 0):
    i += 1
```

Then, after increasing the number of calculated factorials, `S(100)` returns `2012` as required.

EDIT:
`while not (factorials[i] % n == 0):` can make use of the faultyness of 0 and thus be shortened to `while factorials[i] % n:` as COLDSPEED pointed out.